# Iterating over an empty list

Tags: python, for-loop

Trying to iterate over a list that based on previous conditions, may or may not be empty.

Here's the code:

```
function_name(): 
    for x in gen:
        if x = attacker1:
            gain += 2
        elif x = attacker2:
            gain += 3
        else:
            gain -= 1
    if not gen:
        gain -= 1
    return gain
```

When one of the variables is present in the list, the code works. When no variables are present, the codes does not work and I get the following error message:

*ErrorMessage: local variable 'gain' referenced before assignment*

I've also tried:

```
function_name():      
      for x in gen:
          if x = attacker_1:
              gain += 2
          elif x = attacker2:
              gain += 3
          else:
              gain -= 1
      if gen == False:
          gain -= 1
      return gain
```

The above code gives me the same error message.

Also, not sure if I need the "else" statement in the for loop, but I put in there to be safe.

Any help is much-appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: As an aside to your question, you need to be using `==` for checking equality rather than `=`, which assigns a value to a variable.

Comment: please define the local varible which you have used in code, are they defiend somewhere before this function or are they of typpe global

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gain is not declared anywhere so, you can't do

```
gain += 2
```

Because you can't add 2 to something that doesnt exist yet.

So you have to write

```
gain = 0
```

at the begining of your function.

The error message was quite informative.

Answer (score 1):

That error message is basically saying you need to declare and initialise 'gain' before using it. It's out of scope by the time you're trying to return it.

Try putting

```
gain = 0
```

at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple issues with your code, but the one you're tripping on right now is that `gain` isn't ever declared before it's referenced. Python is happy to let you add to an existing variable, but if `gain` doesn't exist yet, how do we know what its value is? (We might intuitively think it's `0`, but since python isn't sure, it tells you you're referencing the variable before assignment.)

Also, you'll want to watch out - your `if` statements are using assignment `=`, not comparison `==`.

Here's a working version of your code.

```py
def function_name(gen): 
  attacker1 = 0
  attacker2 = 1
  gain = 0
  for x in gen:
    if x == attacker1:
      gain += 2
    elif x == attacker2:
      gain += 3
    else:
      gain -= 1
  if not gen:
    gain -= 1
  return gain

print(function_name([0, 1, 2]))
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/MediumorchidFelineDeclarations)